# What are the interior, boundary, exterior and cluster points of $\{(x,y) | 0 < xy \le 1\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The $xy$ is really confusing me for some reason. My thought the interior points are $[0,1]$ and the exterior points is the compliment of $[0,1]$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hint: let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=xy$, then $f$ is continuous and 
$$
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: 0<xy\leqslant 1\} = f^{-1}((0,1)) \cup f^{-1}(\{1\}),
$$
where $f^{-1}((0,1))$ is open and $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed, by definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

$0<xy$ means you are restricted to the first and third quadrant! $xy \leq 1$ means you are on or under the $y=\frac{1}{x}$ hyperbola for $x>0$ and on or above the hyperbola for $x<0$. Hope this helps you to draw the set correctly in $\mathbb{R^2}$.